# Creating a button that stores speech

Tags: java, android, button, audio, speech

Is there anyway that a button can store sound or even speech. I am trying to create an app that has multiple buttons that store sound or even recorded speech. So far I have had no luck, and I am not too sure on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is you really want, so I suggest you some possible answers:

1. If you want to record sound or voice, you can use recording library.
   https://github.com/steelkiwi/AndroidRecording
2. Or, you just want to play audio file when button was clicked, use media player. 
   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm